# How to make the plot's shape round?

Tags: matplotlib

I have created a plot, which is working just fine.

But I really want to change its shape to a circle.

This is my current plotting code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.plot(30, 80, marker="o", markersize=20, markeredgecolor="#ed6033", markerfacecolor="#ed6033")
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.set_facecolor('#8cc9e2')

ax.margins(0.1)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels()[4], visible=False) 
plt.xlim(10, 90)
plt.ylim(10, 90)
plt.grid(color='white')
plt.show()
```

and this is the output I get:

[image: regular output]

eventually, this is my desired output:

[image: target output]

Answer (score 1):

You can clip the path of artists including the background patch using the path of another artist.

Add this snippet before the `plt.show()` call:

```
clip_path = plt.Circle(
    (0.5, 0.5), 0.5, transform=ax.transAxes, # circle coordinates defined in axes fractions
    fill=None, linewidth=0 # makes circle invisible
)
ax.add_patch(clip_path)
ax.patch.set_clip_path(clip_path)
```

[image]

Comment: I've moved up your rep BUT, the OP has a black border around the circular area...

Comment: @gboffi I assumed that was an unintended artifact of the method OP used to mock the desired output. However, if that is indeed the intended target, then `linewidth=1, edgecolor='black'` instead of `linewidth=0` will deliver the desired results.